# Json.net windows phone 8 development

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am Developing windows phone 8 app on visual studio 2012 for windows phone.....i am trying to use JSON.NET but i keep geeting this error when i install it

Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Please tell me the reason behind it and how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am using visual studio express for windows phone 2012.
try this

PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 4.5.11